# How to pipe data to a program which calls scanf() and read() in Linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe

I have a C program which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[16];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n: %d\n", n);

    int count = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, 16);
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
    printf("read %d bytes\n", count);
}
```

If I pipe data into this program using a command like

```
(echo -en '45\n'; echo -en 'text\n') | ./program
```

only `scanf()` actually reads data. `read()` simply reads 0 bytes.

In other words, the program outputs

```
n: 45
str:
read 0 bytes
```

How can I pipe data to both `scanf()` and `read()`?

**Edit:** Sorry, I should have clarified: I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying the source. Thanks to the people who answered and commented anyway.

Comment: you could start by adding this: #include  <fcntl.h> to your code.

Comment: The return code from scanf() needs to be checked to assure that the operation actually input a value into 'n'.

Comment: Note: read() will not place a null char at the end of the input.  So the code will have to do that, using the return value from the call to read() to determine where to place the null char.  Otherwise, the printf will read right on past the actual str contents, until it (eventually) encounters a null char or causes a seg fault

Comment: If there were actually 16 or more bytes available to read, the read would stop at 16 bytes, however there would be no room in the str array to append a null byte.  suggest changing the size of str to 17, then pre-set the array to all null bytes. this would assure the contents of str would be properly terminated (pre set all the bytes, not just the last byte)

Comment: scanf stopped at the '\n', than that is the first char in the line to be read.

Comment: note this detail about read():  The function returns the number of bytes read. On end-of-file, 0 is returned, on error it returns -1, setting errno to indicate the type of error that occurred.  In this case, it returned 0, meaning it saw end of file.  suggest modifying : (echo -en '45\n'; echo -en 'text\n') to this: (echo -en '45\ntext\n')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not recommended at all to use both file descriptor functions (read) and stream functions (scanf) for the same file descriptor. Functions using `FILE *` (i.e. fread/fprintf/scanf/...) are buffering data while functions using file descriptors (i.e. `read/write/...`) do not use those buffers. In your case, the easiest way to fix the program is to use `fread` instead of `read`. The program may look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int n;
  char str[16];
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("n: %d\n", n);

  int count = fread(str, 16, 1, stdin);
  printf("str: %s\n", str);
  printf("read %d bytes\n", count);
}
```

In your original example, `scanf` has read the input ahead and stored it in its buffer. Because the input was so short and was available immediately it was entirely read to the buffer and your invocation of `read` had nothing more to read.

This does not happen when you enter the input directly from a terminal, because `scanf` does not buffer data beyond one line when reading from a terminal device. This would also not happen if you create a time pause in your piped input for example by a command:

```
(echo -en '45\n'; sleep 1; echo -en 'text\n') | ./program
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without modifying the source? Possibly some way to make sure `scanf` doesn't buffer all of the input?

Comment: @IGNUcius: It's not the call that buffers, it is the strcuture used to scan/read: `FILE`.

Comment: It might be worth to more explicitly state that the underlying concept is the issue: buffered I/O vs unbuffered I/O

Comment: @IGNUcius I do not know a correct solution for this. You can create a time delay when sending data to pipe, or maybe use fcntl when creating the pipe to hack outgoing end of the pipe and make scanf think that he is reading from a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[16];
    setbuf(stdin, NULL); // Ensure that there's no buffering for stdin
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("n: %d\n", n);

    int count = read(STDIN_FILENO, str, 16);
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
    printf("read %d bytes\n", count);
}
```

As the previous answers said, scanf is causing your problem because it uses a buffer. So you can make sure it doesn't by calling`setbuf(stdin,NULL)`.